Scroll Behaviour doens't apply to TopAppBar
I have added a custom ScrollBehavior to my LargeTopAppBar composable:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyApp(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
    var value by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            AppTopBar(
                {
                    SearchFeature(
                        textFieldValue = value,
                        onValueChange = { value = it }
                    )
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            startDestination = MainApp,
            navController = navController,
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
        ) {
            //NavHost content
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppTopBar(
    searchFeature: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior
) {
    LargeTopAppBar(
        modifier = modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        title = { searchFeature() },
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
    )
}

But it seems this behaviour isn't working, because the LargeTopAppbar does not collapse when I scroll up the screen content. what am I doing wrong?
Note: The screen content is in the HomeScreen composable, which is the start destination for the NavHost. It is written like this :
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    categories: List<Category>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
    ) {
        categories.forEach { category ->
            DataCard(title = category.title, imageUrl = category.imageUrl)
        }
    }
}


The reason is you are missing the TopAppBarState.
Add state to the scrollBehavior
From
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()

To
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())


After the change, The Scroll works fine.
Event If you want an example of it, I'm happy to share it with you.
